# Dithering with GIMP python-fu

Tags: gimp, batch-processing, script

I'm using GIMP 2.10.6 on Ubuntu 18.10.
I'm trying to script an automatic image manipulation, and for part of the workflow I need to dither a layer in my image.

I can't find anything in the script-fu/python-fu API that exposes the functionality provided by the dialogue located at **Colors > Dither...**

[image]

Am I missing something?  Or does it just not exist?

Comment: What do you mean by "anything that exposes the functionality"? Haven't you tried it on an image?

Comment: @BillyKerr, I've updated my question so hopefully it's a bit clearer.  I am looking for a way to access this functionality from the python api.

Comment: Hmm . . . so then this is a coding question, and not a graphic design question. That technically makes it off topic here. Perhaps it would be more suitable for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: On the contrary, this is a question about GIMP scripting functionality.  Tags on this site such as "script", "batch-processing", "photoshot-scripting" and their related questions would suggest otherwise.  I'm not asking about Python syntax or about coding practice, I'm asking about available features specific to a graphic design program.

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Using-filters-marked-by-a-G-in-python-fu-GEGL) on gimp-forum(dot)net.  It would seem it doesn't exist, as you say.

Comment: Also there's a more specific *python-fu* tag available over at Stack Overflow - and as far as I can tell, user @xenoid has answered most of these. He also answers graphic design questions here. Hopefully he'll see this and can help more than me.

Comment: Not much to add to this unfortunately...

Comment: @xenoid - oh well, it was worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

The python-fu procedure is

```
pdb.gimp_levels(drawable, channel, low_input, high_input, gamma, low_output, high_output)
```

See the photo, I tested using the blue channel (number 3, as the procedure navigator explains) and my image got more blue!

[image: tested! Works!]

Comment: I'm afraid not. That appears to be the "Colors > Levels..." dialog, particularly when working in one of the color channels.  Dithering is a way to add perceived color depth by adding visual noise.